# Check disk usage of /var/lib/docker

Tags: sudo, docker, disk-usage

I'm on an ubuntu server and want to check a summary of disk usage of directories inside `/var/lib/docker` I'm confused why I'm not able to check the disk usage of all the directories inside `/var/lib/docker` using a glob `*`.

The directory `/var/lib/docker` clearly exists and has directories inside it:

```
$ sudo du -s /var/lib/* | grep docker
865644  /var/lib/docker
8   /var/lib/docker-engine
$ sudo du -s /var/lib/docker/*
du: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/*': No such file or directory
$ sudo file /var/lib/docker
/var/lib/docker: directory
$ sudo ls /var/lib/docker | head -n 1
builder
$ sudo du -s /var/lib/docker/builder
20  /var/lib/docker/builder
```

Why am I getting an error from `du`?

```
du: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/*': No such file or directory
```

My error seems related to being a non-root user because if I switch to the root user then I'm able to issue the `du` command:

```
# du -s /var/lib/docker/* | sort -n
4   /var/lib/docker/runtimes
4   /var/lib/docker/swarm
4   /var/lib/docker/tmp
4   /var/lib/docker/trust
20  /var/lib/docker/builder
20  /var/lib/docker/plugins
36  /var/lib/docker/volumes
60  /var/lib/docker/network
72  /var/lib/docker/buildkit
208 /var/lib/docker/containers
1880    /var/lib/docker/image
863328  /var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

Comment: You don't need a glob at all. `du /var/lib/docker` does the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the error because your (non-root) shell tried to expand the glob `/var/lib/docker/*` and was unable (because /var/lib/docker isn't readable by your user). Your shell then left the glob intact, leaving a literal asterisk for `sudo`, which is what `du` is complaining about:

```
du: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/*': No such file or directory
```

... because there is no file or directory named `*` under /var/lib/docker/.

Answer (score 4):

The `du` command is being executed by the root user, but the glob expansion is done before with your user, and because it can't be expanded (due to the directory permissions), the `du` command uses the literal `*` as part of the path.

If you want to see the size of the folders inside `/var/lib/docker`, you can call a shell with `sudo` and protect the glob expansion (`*`) with single quotes:

```
sudo bash -c 'du -sh /var/lib/docker/*' | sort -h
```

*(I use the human readable (`-h` in `-sh`) format and sort the result based on the sizes returned, but you can change it)*

This way the expansion will be done as the root user (instead of being done with your user).